# Hiding sound files from Nokia S60 music player

Tags: file-management, music, mobile-phone, s60

I have a Nokia S60 (v3fp2) phone that has the Nokia Music Player for listening to music. The problem is I have other sound material - one example is some audio books as mp3 files - on the memory card as well, along with music. Of course, these other files aren't in the Music folder of the memory card, they are organized into a separate folder. However, the Nokia Music Player doesn't seem to care - it just goes and scans the entire memory disk for suitable files, and adds them to the music library. I'd love to restrict it to only the music folder - I keep all my music files there - but that doesn't seem to be an option.

**Is there a way to hide some folders from the Nokia Music Player?**

Some sort of hackaround is quite ok for this purpose, but the files would still need to be accessible from the Nokia File Manager, so that I can listen to them directly.

The Nokia Music Player is quite suitable for my simple music listening needs, and I prefer using software that comes with the device. However, if there is no way to restrict the player to, I'm also interested in *simple* third party players that have this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This ticket](http://discussions.europe.nokia.com/discussions/board/message?message.uid=391863) on Nokia Support Forum suggests that you change the attribute of files/folders that you don't want Nokia Music Player to find as system files, maybe you could try that approach.
Excerpt:

> To prevent a file or folder with
>   ringtones from being listed in the MP3
>   player:
>   1. Get yourself a file manager that allows you to change file/folder
>   attributes. [Y-Browser](http://www.drjukka.com) will do the job
>
> 2. Create a separate folder and place in it all the ringtones and melodies
>      you want to hide from the player. I
>      recommend using the memory card - this
>      will help you repair the file system
>      in case something goes wrong.
> 3. Open the file manager from Step 1 (not the build-in File Manager) and
>      navigate to the folder from Step 2.
> 4. Change the attributes of the folder to 'System'. For Y-Browser highlight
>      the folder and choose Options ->
>      Attributes then set 'System' to 'Yes'
>      and press Save.
> 5. Exit the file manager and refresh the library of the Music Player. Now
>      the folder/files are not shown in the
>      Music Player/File Manager but are
>      still listed on music file selection
>      dialogs (like 'Ringing tone' option in
>      Contacts).

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of hiding the files from the normal Nokia File Manager as well. However, as you can still use the Y-Browser to access *and play* those files, this is a nice hackaround that does what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy way to do this. This method does not involve keeping your sound files 'hidden'. This means your files will still be accessible from other apps. Also, you DO NOT not need to hack your phone for this.

http://lagenda4046s603rd.blogspot.com/2010/08/13-all-mods-pack-in-sis.html

This little app will let you do exactly what you want. The music library will now only look in E:\music (memorycard>'music' folder)

HOWEVER, when you install it, it will still show your ring tones and other sound files, but it wont show any further sound files that you add to your phone unless you put them in E:\music. THERE IS A VERY EASY WAY AROUND THIS:

BEFORE INSTALLING Just hide all the sound files you don't want in your music library (make files 'hidden'), then install '13 all mods' (link above), then unhide those sound files.

Now your music library will ONLY show music in E:/music AND your other sound files remain unhidden, so other apps can use them normally.

Enjoy!

You can also do other cool things like disable the nokia hands boot screen so your phone turns on faster. All of the features are optional during install. Your phone may not support all the options, but hopefully it will work for the music library function.

When you install, it may say 'phone not supported', BUT INSTALL IT ANYWAY. This just means that not all the extra options will work for your phone (e.g. disable nokia hands), but you should expect the music thing to work properly.

Note: this app will not show an icon in you menu, but it will be in you app list in 'application manager'. There, you can uninstall it, and this will undo any features you selected i.e. it will show all your sound files, ring tones and it will re-enable nokia-hands etc.

Regards and Good luck

waterer from ipmart

Comment: Interesting! Is this safe to use? Does it need to be self-signed before installing?